# sqlite3 update text in uitextview

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitextview, detailsview

i had the sqlite statement ready for update..but i am confuse about grabbing text from uitextview and updating it..and i waned to update it using a uibutton..how do i carry on after creating the sql statement???kinda lost..any new solution is appreciate..

```
- (void) saveAllData {
    if(isDirty) {
        if(updateStmt == nil) {
            const char *sql = "update Snap Set snapTitle = ?, snapDesc = ?, Where snapID = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [snapTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [snapDescription UTF8String], -2, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, snapID);
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
                isDirty = NO;
            }

        //Reclaim all memory here.
        [snapTitle release];
        snapTitle = nil;
        [snapDescription release];
        snapDescription = nil;

        //isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sqlite3_reset(updateStmt)` I use `sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt)` and the code runs fine.